# Is it possible to have the linear gauge pointer start from the center?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a case where I measure negative and positive speed using the same linear gauge. I was wondering if it's possible to have the pointer start with the center as a zero-point? Here's my code:

```
<script>
    function createSpeedGauge() {
        $("#speedBar").kendoLinearGauge({
            pointer: {
                value: 0,
                color: "black",
                start: 0
            },
            scale: {
                majorUnit: 20,
                minorUnit: 2,
                min: -120,
                max: 120,
                vertical: true,
                reverse: true,
                ranges: [
                    {
                        from: -120,
                        to: -30,
                        color: "#ffc700"
                    },
                    {
                        from: 120,
                        to: 30,
                        color: "#ffc700"
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        createSpeedGauge();
    });
</script>
```

[image: Dashboard]

I've attached an image of how it's setup (the gauge in question on the right side). If this was setup the way I wanted, this gauge would've read -120 from this picture. (Right now, it reads "0" on the black bar, as this is the value set in my js.) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting the starting point to 0 and using SignalR to update the other end of the bar. (Initial starting point)